# How do I develop a video codec in C/C++?

Tags: video, codec, video-codecs

How do I develop a video codec in C/C++? What do I need? I'm trying to understand how Video Codec Developers came up with video codecs, and honestly I'm getting nothing out of my reasonings, can someone help me by giving me an beginner-frendly explanation?

I have done some research on video codec development and have learned about some of the basic concepts and techniques involved, such as compression algorithms and video file formats. However, I am still not sure how to put these pieces together to create a functional video codec.

I have tried reading documentation and articles online, as well as studying existing video codecs to get a better understanding of how they work. I have also experimented with some basic coding exercises in C/C++ to improve my skills and get a feel for the language.

However, I am still struggling to understand the overall process and specific steps involved in developing a video codec. I am not sure how to approach the problem or what specific techniques and approaches are commonly used in video codec development.

I was expecting to find more detailed guidance or resources on how to develop a video codec in C/C++, but so far I have been unable to find anything that covers the topic in sufficient depth. I am hoping to get some help or guidance from the community to better understand how to proceed.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. It seems you have not even settled on how your video format even works, let alone developing a codec for it. Note that "codec" is usually referring to a standardized interface for plugging video formats into certain software. Normally, the video format comes first. If you have enough reason to create your own video format to begin with, start there. Then worry about encapsulating that as a codec. Note that creating a video format is _not_ really the next step for someone who is a beginner. "Basic coding exercises" are not a sufficient prerequisite.

Comment: My question was more about "How do I even start"? Because I know some concepts in C and C++ but no Idea on how to build a video codec with them, just a curiosity.

Comment: A codec is essentially comprised of two functions. One encodes a video stream. The other decodes a video stream. This is how the word "codec" is derived: _encode / decode_.